# Error handling in C library used by C++ program

Tags: c++, c, error-handling

I am using a C library (which I also wrote) within a C++ program and I want to know how I should be doing error handling from within the C library such that the C++ program is able to decide how to handle errors that may happen.

I originally had the C library return a value indicating an error has occurred (e.g. NULL or -1) and just print an error message to stderr but this is not easily capturable by programs using the library.

Ideally I want the C++ program to be able to retrieve an error message string from the C library so that it can handle the error whichever way it wants to, such as logging the error message elsewhere.

Is there a common design idiom for this?

Comment: Yes: return informative error codes. Or use an `errno`-equivalent, but then you have concurrency/re-rentrancy concerns.

Comment: Usage of return values for Error/Status codes is common in C. You can define your status codes in your C-library and provide a way of getting a string given such a status code.

Comment: I want the program using this library to be able to get a custom error message string whenever an error has occurred, so not just the standard set of errno messages. Is creating my own "*get_last_error*" function a common practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

All methods, that require global state (errno, get_last_error, ...), will have concurrency issues. Using the return channel ruins return value optimization for you.

A common option is to take a pointer to an error struct as first or last parameter.

```c
struct Error {
    const char* message;
    int         code;
};

int my_nice_c_function( int a, int b, Error* err ) {
    if ( err != NULL ) {
        err->message = "";
        err->code    = 0;
    }

    return a + b;
}
```

When you pass them in from C++ it could look like:

```cpp
Error err;
...
auto foo = my_nice_c_function( 5, 6, &err );
if ( err.code != 0 ) {
    std::cerr << err.message << std::endl;
}
```

But make sure to always set the error members!